# Paths are homotopic if and only if they are in the same path connected component of the space of all paths in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is a question from Gamelin and Greene's Introduction to Topology. 
Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, and let $a,b \in X$. Write $P$ as the set of all paths from $a$ to $b$, and define a metric $\rho(\alpha, \beta) = \sup\{d(\alpha(s),\beta(s)) \mid 0 \le s \le 1\}$. Show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are path homotopic if and only if they are in the same path connected component of $P$.
I've been thinking about it a while and having trouble, so I looked at the back of the book for a little hint. It said to consider the correspondence $\gamma(s,t) = \gamma_t(s)$, so here comes my main question. I think I'm just mixed up with what is what space. So to check that $\gamma(s,t)$ is a path homotopy from $\alpha$ to $\beta$, I need to check the four conditions as well as continuity. But $\gamma(0,t) = \gamma_t(0)$ should be equal to $\alpha(0)$, but I don't really understand how that makes sense. Additionally, when checking $h_t$ is continuous, am I supposed to mess around with the metric? Thanks, sorry, my mind is all over the place trying to understand the content of the question.

Comment: what's the question here

Comment: This question is currently too confused to address any part of it. While it's fine to be confused, you should try to formulate a coherent question so someone can answer it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've taken a rest to collect my thoughts, and I'll edit it again once I find a better formulation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The idea is that a path in the path space $P$ is essentially the same thing as a homotopy between the paths in $X$. Note that points of $P$ are paths of $X$.